# Symfony2 translation alias/parameter

Tags: symfony, internationalization

For the highest flexibility, I wan't the user to be able to define different translation for a key depending on the template he is viewing. For better demonstration, here is an example:

```
navbar:
    foo: bar
    bar: foo
    login: %login%
sidebar:
    lorem: ipsum
    login: %login%
login: Login
```

In this example `navbar.login` and `sidebar.login` would point to `login`.

This is comparable with symfony's default parameter handling, but I want something template-specific.

Comment: How do you make it template specific?

Comment: @Wouter: Thats what I ask for.

Comment: But what do you mean by it?

Answer (score 2):

I found aliases in YAML, that are pretty useful

```
aliases:
    - &login Login
navbar:
    foo: bar
    bar: foo
    login: *login
sidebar:
    lorem: ipsum
    login: *login
```